# Can't put a space between output and input on the same line

Tags: printf, scanf, c99

After printing, if I write the name I get:

> Insert a name :Andrea

[image]

There is no space before Andrea, even if I put the space in the output. How can I add a space before writing the name?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int string[8];
    printf("\nInsert a name : ");
    printf(" ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("\nThe name is : %s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing. All those spaces in the printf statements will be printed in any 'normal' C environment. How are you running this?  Here is the input/output line from me running your exact code: `Insert a name :  something` - note two spaces after the colon, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you provided does not compile because the variable `string` is an array of integers (and not a string as you might think). And when you input the value of it, you're telling the compiler to expect a string (`"%s"` in `scanf("%s", string")`).

Change your `string` declaration to `char string[8]` and it should work (with the spacing you want):

[image]

Note that the value that goes into `string` will not contain more than 8 characters.

Comment: I changed int to char but I still can't get a space before the input

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what's going on? Because I just compiled the program and it worked just fine

Comment: I've just added the screenshot

Comment: Try to execute from the terminal, maybe it's the IDE?

Comment: I tried with the terminal and it works perfectly. Thanks! It was because of CLion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you did a small mistake in your `code`, you declared the `string` to be an `array of int` & from the code `scanf("%s", string")` the `compiler` expects from the `user` to enter a `string` as it contains `%s` as the `format specifier`. Hence, the code doesn't `compile`.

In order to correct this, you should declare string as `char string[8]` (string containing 8 characters).

The `correct code` is given below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[8];
    printf("\nInsert a name : ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("\nThe name is : %s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

From the above correction your problem for space between input and output will be solved!

Here, is the `output` which is received from this correction :

[image]

I hope so this explanation will be helpful for you!

If any problem persists then feel free to ask in `comments`! ;-)